# Conditional JavaScript is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am working on a project and I am using bootstrap. I changed the default behavior of `onClick` to `hover`, on above 600 and equal to 600 size ( i.e >= 600 screensize) I want to execute the if body. And on less then 600 size of screen I don't want that code to be executed. BUT on less then 600 screen size if body is executed else part(which is by default on click method of bootstrap) is not executed.

```
if (screen.width >= 600) { 

    $(function(){
        $('ul.nav li.dropdown').hover(function(){
            $('.dropdown-menu', this).fadeIn();
        },function(){
            $('.dropdown-menu', this).fadeOut('fast');
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: explaining is not your forte

Comment: good guess @madalinivascu

Answer (score 1):

Since explanation is not clear,Hope you want below piece of condition as per my understanding

```
      function sizeFunc(){
        var screenWidth = $(window).width();
        $('ul.nav li.dropdown').hover(function(){
            if(screenWidth  >= 600){
             $('.dropdown-menu', this).fadeIn();
           }
        },function(){
            if(screenWidth  < 600){
            $('.dropdown-menu', this).fadeOut('fast');
           }
        });
       }
    $(function(){
         sizeFunc();//on begin
         $(window).on("resize",sizeFunc);//on every window size change
    });
```

Comment: @Jam, glad to help you

Comment: I don't know why it's not working for me, my code is pastebin.com/61J5Z6Ds @mymotherland

Comment: @Jam I have updated my answer which is not tested. Please check and let me know.